# Newbie Building Reports with Microsoft Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I have an Access db file, and I need to slice and dice the data for various reports that my boss wants.

Is Microsoft Reporting Services a tool that is appropriate for this kind of activity?
If so, would I import the Access data in SQL Server, then the reporting services is a tool that works on SQL Server, allowing the report builder to build custom reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS is great for what your trying to do if you wish to stick with Micrsoft tech.

SQL Server Express Adv edition comes with report server. There are plenty of guides out there for install / set up but once going you can use a little application called Report Builder that lets you design the layout of the reports themselves.

Reporting server esentially generates reports from templates you produce in report builder app.

The free edition of report server that comees with SQL Express Adv can export reports into three types, word files, excell or PDFs and does a very good job at it. It also exposes a webservice with a whole myrad of web methods thats very very usefull. ASP.Net also has a control which you can drop into your apps which will render a report.

So in short, yes :)

Hope this helps.